# Expression has changed after it was checked - angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

When I call a service in (change) action method , I got this error :

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
>   has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-untouched:
>   true'. Current value: 'ng-untouched: false'

My code :

```
onChange(event) { 

  const messageToDisplay = "Message test";
  this.popinService.open(messageToDisplay).subscribe((result: ConfirmPopinResultType) => {
    if (result === ConfirmPopinResultType.CONFIRM) {
      console.log("test");
    }
  });        
}
```

onChange is an event handler on an input reactive form  (select dropdown list)

```
<form [formGroup]="poolForm"> 
  <select id="pool-select" #item (change)="item.value = onChangePool(item.value)" formControlName="item"> 
     <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.name">{{ item.name }}</option> 
  </select> 
</form>
```

The exception error occurs when I call the poppin service on Change event handler (that display a pop up with two button Confirm and Cancel)

thank for your help!

Comment: That's a very common problem with the change detection mechanisms in Angular 2+. Have you had a look at [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)?

Comment: It means you are changing the value of something at the wrong time in angular's lifecycle. Here is a good starting point: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks The solution for many (but not all) lifecycle issues is to put a setTimeout around the assignment to a new variable so instead of `foo = bar;` you write`setTimeout( () => { foo = bar; }, 0);`

Comment: I have tried all solution that i found but still not works :( , I used also setTimout() but it is not working : setTimeout(()=>{
   this.popinService.open(messageToDisplay).subscribe((result: ConfirmPopinResultType) => {
    if (result === ConfirmPopinResultType.CONFIRM) {
      console.log("test");
    }
  });      
  
});

Comment: Please help ! , i am blocked all the day :(

Comment: Did you try adding  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, to your component

Comment: @Abadou please provide more info about what is going on in the service

Comment: @Naga Sai A , ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush I tried it , it elimante the exception but it caused me a malfunction at a call service level in ngOnInit

Comment: @AdamGenshaft , The Service is display a popup with some text and two buttons : Cancel and Confirm, this is the 'open' function in service that i call :  open(message: string, messageSubtitle?: string): Observable<any> {
  return from(this.openConfirm(BasicConfirmPopinComponent, { message, messageSubtitle })
   .result)
   .pipe(catchError(error => of(false)));
 }

Answer (score 7):

You are listening to DOM element events.

```
(change)="onChange(item.value)"
```

And you are receiving an error relative to Angular forms.

> Previous value: 'ng-untouched: true'. Current value: 'ng-untouched: false'

The two are in conflict

 because the `ngModel` is tracking changes to the form component.

 Angular Forms use `(ngModelChange)` to notify of component changes.

 Angular Reactive Forms use `valueChanges` observables.

You haven't shared where you've attached the `(change)` event handler, but it's clearly on a form input that is also being used by `ngModel`.

You should be using `(ngModelChange)` instead of `(change)`.

Comment: yes the change event handler is on an form input, i have tried (ngModelChange) instead of (change) but I have the same problem :( , this my template :   <form [formGroup]="poolForm">

<select id="pool-select" #item (change)="item.value = onChangePool(item.value)" formControlName="item">
  <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.name">{{ item.name }}</option>
 </select>
    
    </form>                                                                                         the change event call a service to display a pop up message with two button confirm and cancel.

Comment: I add that the problem occurs when I call this service on Change event handler : this.popinService.open(messageToDisplay).subscribe((result: ConfirmPopinResultType) => {
    if (result === ConfirmPopinResultType.CONFIRM) {
      console.log("test");
    }
  });